# merging file - whats wrong?

Tags: awk, merge

Where is a problem in my script I would like to compare $1 (first file) with $21 (second file). everything by awk and tab delimited.

```
INPUT:
1st file:
1         soup
3         bread
5         roll

2nd file:
a....$20   1
b....$20   2
c....$20   3
d....$20   4
e....$20   5

OUTPUT
a....$20   1   soup
b....$20   2   
c....$20   3   bread
..etc..

MY SCRIPT


awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {if($21 in a) print $0a,[$2]; else print $0}' file2 file1
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is it in my question like OUTPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your codes, change:

```
if($21 in a) print $0a,[$2]
```

into

```
if($21 in a) print $0, a[$21]
```

also, change the parameter to your awk command

from:

```
file2, file1
```

into:

```
file1, file2
```

Comment: @Vonton ok, don't know you meant that, fixed in answer.